# .Net Port Sharing EndpointNotFound

Tags: .net, wcf, tcpportsharing

I have two machines `host1` & `host2`. `host1` is running a process communicating with a process on `host2` with following two services:

```
net.tcp://host2:1000/Service1
net.tcp://host2:1001/Service2
```

While `Service1` works fine `Service2` return following error on `host1`:

```
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: Could not connect to net.tcp://host2:1001/Service2...no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

From `host1` I did `telnet host2 1001` which does succeed. I also tried `netsh http show urlacl` on both machines but it contained no information regarding my services.

How can I further debug this issue? what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to try:

1. You may need a port per binding (pick a port to use for TCP, one for HTTP maybe).
2. Check to see if port 1001 is occupied by a program, or you can replace port 1001 with 1000.
3. Review the ABCs of WCF - Address, Binding and Contract. The client must match the service to connect.

Comment: And don't forget to open port in firewall